# How tag COLGROUP works with two col=100%?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I used COLGROUP to layout table, I found a scenarios that I can not understand, please anyone can tell me the principle COLGROUP works:

1. I add WIDTH attribute for table, the two COL with width equal 100% can display as 50%，50%

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMfvn.png)

2. I remove WIDTH attribute, the layout is changed, and the layout out our control:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da9mP.png)

please anyone can tell why the two ways render different layout?

Comment: Please put your code into the question, formatted as code, not as an image

Comment: In your code the body is the parent of table so it's taking `width:100%;` you need to write table inside any specific div which contains some width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the `<body>` is the parent of table so it's taking `width:100%;` you need to write table inside any specific div which contains some width

like this, you will try.

```html
<body>
  <div class="table-container" style="width: 500px;">
    <table style="table-layout: fixed">
      <colgroup>
      <col width="50px">
      <col width="100%">
      <col width="50px">
      <col width="100%">
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Minal Chauhan, Meraj Khan! I still want to know that why there will generate different layout  between [table width as width=100%] and [table width as width=500]? I want to know more about TABLE how to render it.

Comment: if you give specific width then that width will be calculated otherwise by default `width: 100%;` work. Read this about table https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

Comment: if it is useful appreciate. :)

Comment: thank u, but i am surprised the two col[width=100%] will be calculated as 50% 50% in remaining width when table width specified.